# multiple user_pseudo_id in firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have a project in Firebase and I have verified that the new users that Firebase reports to me through the first_open event with update_with_analytics = 0 does not match the real number of new users.

When checking if there were different user_pseudo_id for the same advertising_id and I know that one advertising_id can have distinct user_pseudo_id because of app uninstalls or cache cleanups.
The problem us I have observed that there are advertising_id with a large number of different user_pseudo_id, even 30 and 40 daily. This happen mainly in IOS. The image below shows the first_open events in one day for the same advertising_id, but different user_pseudo_id

[image]

For one of these advertising_id, there are first_open records of 365 different user_pseudo_id in less than a month for the same advertising_id. Even setting "Default reporting identity" as "By userID then Device" does not seem normal for this to happen so many times.

What could be the reason? What would be the solution?

Thank you